# Dual Boot Ubuntu 12.04 on a Thinkpad T420 but keep recovery partition

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, data-recovery, thinkpad

I have a Thinkpad T420 which runs on Windows 7 Pro and I would like to install Ubuntu 12.04 on it via Dual Boot. But the thing is, I'd like to keep the Thinkvantage Recovery Partition. I've been researching and found this:

[Install Ubuntu on ThinkPad, recovery section must remain intact](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31731/install-ubuntu-on-thinkpad-recovery-section-must-remain-intact)

and

http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Rescue_and_Recovery

But the information doesn't seem to be updated for for my situation (the second link indicates that it won't work with Windows 7). Just wonderin' if anyone already has experience doing this?

I could create recovery CD/DVD's but I'll be more happy i can keep recovery partition and boot information on the hard drive functional (for future resale purposes).

Any Ideas?

Comment: How will you be installing Ubuntu?

Comment: Planning to create a USB based installer based on a 64bit iso.

Answer (score 1):

Create a partition in Windows 7, say 50GB. Then run the installation CD and make partitions, such as:

- `/boot` 500 MG
- `/` 15 GB
- `/home` - the rest